# How do I send an email with HTML with an address the user inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, email, mailto

I have an app i am designing and there is a page for emails. The user inputs their name, email address and message and then clicks 'submit'. this works, but i don't know how to make the user's input be on the email. this is the code so far;

```
<form id="contacts-form" action="mailto:megan.sime@idoxgroup.com">
    <ul class = "rounded">
        <li style = "color: #FFFFFF">Full Name:<input type="text" placeholder = "J. Doe" name = "signature" id = 'signature' /></li>
        <li style = "color: #FFFFFF">E-mail:<input type="text" placeholder = "www.example@examplemail.com" name = "address" id = 'address' /></li>
        <li style = "color: #FFFFFF">Message:<input type = "text" placeholder = "Message" name = "message" id = 'message' /></li>

        <a href="mailto:address?subject=subject&body=message" class="button">Submit</a>
    </ul>
</form>
```

does anyone know how to change the code to allow the user input to go onto the email? Thanks a lot in advance x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use javascript to obtain the input values. With `onclick="javascript:window.location='putURLhere'"` you can imitate a link. What's left now is to create a URL that contains your values, which you can get with `document.getElementById(id).value`. With `+` you can concatenate them.

Example:

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.location='mailto:?subject=Message from '+document.getElementById('address').value+'&body='+document.getElementById('message').value">Submit</a>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot - would it be right to add 'mailto:'+document.getElementById('address')+'? etc into the code? i think i get this now :)

Comment: Good! You can leave the `action` part from the `form` tag, that is only used in combination with the `<input type="submit">` element and usually links to a separate PHP or ASP page that will handle the results.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing a function like this:

```
function sendEmail(){
    var addr = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var sig = document.getElementById('signature').value;
    var msg= document.getElementById('message').value;

    //concatenate to string to build URL
    var url = "mailto:" + .... + addr + ...;
    location.href = url; //(might want to use window.location or something else here)
}
```

And then change your link to:

```
<a href="javasctipt:void(0)" onclick="javascript:sendEmail()" class="button">Submit</a>
```

Comment: ok thanks. in the var url part is an example of what you would replace the ... with;
"mailto:" + "http://www." + addr;??

Comment: the var url will be used to build up your concatenated string **mailto:address?subject=subject&body=message** with the address/message etc replaced with your vars

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you are asking by "allow the user input to go onto the email", but using `document.getElementById('signature').value` will return the input's value. You can then include that in your post/get.

Comment: i mean like for example in the input tag for 'email', the address they put in is the address the computer emails the message to.

Comment: ok, use roelandvanbeek's solution. Using 'document.getElementById('address').value' will return the input from that element. take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: How familiar with javascript are you?

Comment: i'd say average - i've ot studied at university yet but ve been researching for a while for my internship

Comment: Ok, well is this form that you are making meant to email the message to the specified recipient? Without opening the default email client?

Comment: the form is meant to email the recipient the user specifies in the input field 'address' it's not specified in my task whether or not the email shoudl open but i think it should so the user is able to check the email first and to see it works

Comment: ok, well you would have had to use PHP or ASP to send the email automatically, but if that's not defined in your task then I wouldn't worry about it. Good luck.